# Is my solution to $a^x=x+b$ correct?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I was trying to find a general solution to the equation $a^x=x+b$. First, I used a substitution:

$$u=a^x\Longleftrightarrow x=\log_au$$

Then, it went as follows:

$$u=\log_a u+b$$
$$-b=\log_a u-u$$
$$-b=\log_a u-\log_a a^u$$
$$-b=\log_a ua^{-u}$$
$$a^{-b}=ua^{-u}$$
$$-a^{-b}=-ua^{-u}$$
$$-u=W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\,\big)$$
$$u=-W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\,\big)$$
$$a^x=-W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\,\big)$$

I finally got the solution of:

$$x={{\ln\Big(\!-W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\,\big)\Big)}\over{\ln a}}$$

**The problem:**

From a paper on the Lambert W function, it says that a general solution to the same equation is:

$$x=-b-{{W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\;\ln a\,\big)}\over{\ln a}}$$

which is quite different from what I got. I thought that maybe it is the same thing, but I wasn't able to manipulate my answer to get to the paper's answer.

So, the question is, how do I prove or disprove that:

$${{\ln\Big(\!-W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\,\big)\Big)}\over{\ln a}}=-b-{{W\big(\!-\!a^{-b}\;\ln a\,\big)}\over{\ln a}}$$

**EDIT:** As Ahmed noted in the comments, I made an error in my work, I mistaked $-ua^{-u}$ for $-ue^{-u}$, and incorrectly took the Lambert W function of it, instead of changing the exp base first. When I corrected myself, I managed to arrive at the correct answer.

Comment: How’d you go from $-ua^{-u}=-a^{-b}$ to $-u=W(-a^b)$. What if $a \neq e$? The inverse of $x\color{red}{e}^x$ is $W(x)$.

Comment: Oh! I'm so stupid, that's what happens when I do math in the middle of the night. Thank you, so it seems my answer is incorrect.

Comment: No you’re not :). We all make mistakes...

Comment: I don't know where you found the solution. To me, it should be $$x=-b-\frac{W\left(-a^{-b} \log (a)\right)}{\log (a)}$$ Typo's ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes that's a typo, I'll fix my question. And also btw, I did it correctly now and arrived at the correct answer. Thanks to Ahmed for spotting my error :)

Comment: Good to know all of that ! Cheers.